# IndexError when ploting sklearn manifold TSNE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scatter-plot

I try to run a t-sne but python shows me this error:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Data is being provided by this [link](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv).

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

#Step 1 - Download the data
dataframe_all = pd.read_csv('https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv')
num_rows = dataframe_all.shape[0]

#Step 2 - Clearn the data
#count the number of missing elements (NaN) in  each column
counter_nan = dataframe_all.isnull().sum()
counter_without_nan = counter_nan[counter_nan==0]
#remove the columns with missing elements
dataframe_all = dataframe_all[counter_without_nan.keys()]
#remove the first 7 columns which contain no descriminative information
dataframe_all = dataframe_all.ix[:,7:]

#Step 3: Create feature vectors
x = dataframe_all.ix[:,:-1].values
standard_scalar = StandardScaler()
x_std = standard_scalar.fit_transform(x)

# t distributed stochastic neighbour embedding (t-SNE) visualization
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state = 0)
x_test_2d = tsne.fit_transform(x_std)

#scatter plot the sample points among 5 classes
markers=('s','d','o','^','v')
color_map = {0:'red', 1:'blue', 2:'lightgreen', 3:'purple', 4:'cyan'}
plt.figure()
for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(x_test_2d)):
    plt.scatter(x=x_test_2d[cl, 0],y =x_test_2d[cl, 1], c=color_map[idx], marker=markers[idx], label=cl)
plt.show()
```

What do I have to change in order to make this work?

Comment: you need to add some data in order to help you

Comment: Data is being provided by this link: https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv

Comment: see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the following line:

`plt.scatter(x_test_2d[cl, 0], x_test_2d[cl, 1], c=color_map[idx], marker=markers[idx])`

---

Here, `cl` can take and takes not integer values (from `np.unique(x_test_2d)`) and this raises the error, e.g. the last value that `cl` takes is `99.46295` and then you use: `x_test_2d[cl, 0]` which translates into `x_test_2d[99.46295, 0]`

---

**Define** a variable `y` that **hold** the class **labels**, then use:

```
# variable holding the classes
y = dataframe_all.classe.values
y = np.array([ord(i) for i in y])

#scatter plot the sample points among 5 classes
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x_test_2d[:, 0], x_test_2d[:, 1], c = y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**FULL CODE:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

#Step 1 - Download the data
dataframe_all = pd.read_csv('https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv')
num_rows = dataframe_all.shape[0]

#Step 2 - Clearn the data
#count the number of missing elements (NaN) in  each column
counter_nan = dataframe_all.isnull().sum()
counter_without_nan = counter_nan[counter_nan==0]
#remove the columns with missing elements
dataframe_all = dataframe_all[counter_without_nan.keys()]
#remove the first 7 columns which contain no descriminative information
dataframe_all = dataframe_all.ix[:,7:]

#Step 3: Create feature vectors
x = dataframe_all.ix[:,:-1].values
standard_scalar = StandardScaler()
x_std = standard_scalar.fit_transform(x)

# t distributed stochastic neighbour embedding (t-SNE) visualization
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state = 0)
x_test_2d = tsne.fit_transform(x_std)

# variable holding the classes
y = dataframe_all.classe.values # you need this for the colors
y = np.array([ord(i) for i in y]) # convert letters to numbers

#scatter plot the sample points among 5 classes
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x_test_2d[:, 0], x_test_2d[:, 1], c = y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I definetely understand what the problem is now. Could you still help me with implementing your suggested code to my program? Unfortunately im relatively new when it comes to coding :/

Comment: Just replace the last 5 lines in you code with these lines from my answer. Also upvote and accept my answer of it helps

Comment: @AiropX I have updated my answer. consider accepting it.